# Run a python script to generate a file that can be downloaded on web

Tags: javascript, python, html, css

I've been working on this Python script that creates an excel file, but I wanted to be able to distribute the script by creating a website that can run the script and download the file.

```
  <a href="file:shift.xlsx" target="_blank">
      <h3>Download Schedule</h3>
  </a>

  <input type="button" id='script' name="scriptbutton" value=" Run Script " onclick="goPython()">

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script>

    function goPython() {
      $.ajax({
        alert("Check"),
        type: "POST",
        url: "main.py",
      }).done(function(o) {
        alert("Complete")
      });
    }
  </script>
```

The python code is as follows:

```
import xlsxwriter
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('shift.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet.write(0,0,     "test")
workbook.close()
```

When I try to download the file it says that it can't be found. Is it possible to do this without Django or Flask? Thanks!

Comment: Try with fullpath in the a.ref attribute to your file and if it still fails open your browser's console in the "network" tab, it should show the actual path where it's looking for your file

Comment: Can you post the python code too?

Comment: Also, I think you are missing a `,` after `alert("Check")`!

Comment: I fixed the comma and posted the python